# Proving that the quotient map is a surjective group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

> Given $G$ a group and $K$ a normal subgroup, the map $f: G \to G/K$ is a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $K$.

Here is my attempt.

> Given $aK \in G/K$, $f(a) = aK$, so $f$ is surjective. Given $a,b \in G$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> f(ab) = (ab)K = aK bK = f(a) f(b),
> \end{align*}
> which is a well-defined multiplication of cosets since $K$ is normal. Finally, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> a \in \mathrm{ker}(f) \iff f(a) = eK = K \iff aK = K \iff a \in K.
> \end{align*}

How does this look? The only thing I am not completely sure about is the proof for the kernel. I'm not completely certain that every step I wrote down, specifically the last one, is reversible.

Comment: It's perfect. However, if you are uncertain, just try to separately prove the two implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Concerning your doubts:
If $a \in K$, then $ag \in K$ for every $g \in K$ since $K$ is a subgroup. If $aK = K$ then $a = a e \in K$ since $e \in K$.